# Angularjs model update delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems there's a delay when updating the model.
if I submit the form immediately after updating the model the old data will be submitted, but if I submit after 1 second it works correctly:

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/zexeko/4/edit?html,js)

**Edit 1**: Demo code is just simplified version of my final code to demonstrate the problem: when the form is submitted value of 'city' field is 'NY' not 'LA'.

**Edit 2**: Thanks for all the suggestions towards the best practices and alternative methods but I asked this question to know if using angularjs can cause a latency in the binding and if the answer is yes then won't it make unsafe to use?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by submit the old data?Are you referring to clicking on click here?Normally updating the text field showed an immediate change in the text to the right.

Comment: iirc, angular use a digest cycle and dirty checking to do the two-way binding, thus the view is not updated yet by the time ur submit method call.

Comment: @SatejS by old data I meant the initial value of 'city' hidden field which is 'NY'

Comment: @HarryLim it seems you have pointed to the root cause. the value which is sent by the form is important not the view, so is there an angularjs version of submitting the form in the `$scope.city` function which regards the model update delay?

Comment: i think it is depend on what are you trying to do. Can't you submit the data using a POST request (which is common for Angular SPA) ?

Comment: I've already solved my problem with the setTimeout but still can't understand why it doesn't work without it

Answer (score 3):

Use `ngSubmit` and a button instead of a link and `ngClick`. I think the problem is, that you trigger your form submit manually inside your method. That's not neccessary. Btw you should avoid using jQuery `$("...")` with angular because most changes you do with jQuery will not be recognized by angular

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <input type="text" name="city" id="city" ng-model="city">{{ city }}
  <button type="submit">Click Here</button>
</form>
```

Comment: on my app user does some kind of interaction and based on that I have to send him to another page with some POST data, so the form is completely hidden to the user and that's the reason I used the jQuery code to submit the form. is there a better way to submit the form from controller?

Answer (score 0):

**I warmly suggest you not to perform Jquery code in Angularjs:**

```
AVOID: $("#myform").submit();
```

On top of that I don't get the point using angularjs for this use case.
You are not embracing angularjs best practice, i.e. you should send the information through a POST service, while you are using the standard html POST request.

I hope it helps.

Comment: the sample code is just a small part of my final code. the form is not visible to the user hence I had to invoke the form submission somehow and I couldn't find the angularjs way.

Comment: if the form is hidden then you don't even need a html form, you can simply send the POST request to your server/API through the $http service.

Comment: Because the user has to go to the next page and in that page we do some processing based on the form data so I can't use $http service (XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: you can post the data and the redirect the user to next page.